# Proving that $a \dot{-} (b+1) = (a \dot{-} b) \dot{-} 1$

Tags: arithmetic, computability

This should be an easy exercise from Hodel's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, but for some reason I'm not getting it right. Define $a \dot{-} b$ as $a-b$ if $a \geq b$ and as $0$ otherwise. Recursively, this can be defined as $\mu x [(a=b+x) \vee (a<b)]$. Using this information, I'm supposed to prove that $a \dot{-} (b+1) = (a \dot{-} b) \dot{-} 1$. I've tried using induction on $a$ and induction on $b$ to get the desired result, but I got stuck as I see no way of applying the induction step (basically, I couldn't reduce the case, say, $a \dot{-} ((n+1)+1)$ to the induction hypothesis). Any hints?

Comment: I wouldn't think induction works.  You could try cases: $a\geq b+1$, $a\geq b$ but $a<b+1$, $a<b$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 - I thought of trying by cases. But how would I proceed in the case $a > b+1$ without using induction?

Comment: If $a\geq b+1$, then $a\dot{-}(b+1)=a-(b+1)$ and $(a\dot{-}b)\dot{-}1=(a-b)\dot{-}1$.  But, $a-b\geq 1$.  So, $(a-b)\dot{-}1=(a-b)-1$, which is the same as $a-(b+1)$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 - Hmm, I didn't think I was allowed to use the properties of (normal) subtraction, at least not without proving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is mechanical if one uses the *universal property* of the $\,\rm max\,$ function

$$ x \ge y,z\color{#c00}\iff x \ge m(y,z),\ \ m = \rm max\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ $$

Using this property to eliminate then reintroduce $\,m = \rm max\,$ we obtain (in gory detail)

$$\begin{array}{rrl} 
&x\ \ge&\ \,(a \dot- b)\! \dot-\! 1\\
\iff &x\ \ge&\!\!\!m( a \dot- b\! -\!1, 0)\\
\color{#c00}\iff &x\ \ge& \ \ \ a\dot- b\!-\!1, 0\\
\iff &1\!+\!x\ \ge& \ \ \ a \dot- b,\quad \ \, 1\\
\iff &1\!+\!x\ \ge&\!\!\!m(a\!-\!b,0), 1\\
\color{#c00}\iff &1\!+\!x\ \ge&\ \ \,a\!-\!b,\,0, \  1\\
\iff &1\!+\!x\ \ge&\,\ \  a\!-\!b,\quad\,\ 1\\
\iff &x\ \ge&\ \ \  a\!-\!b\!-\!1, 0\\
\color{#c00}\iff &x\ \ge&\!\!\! m(a\!-\!b\!-\!1, 0)\\
\iff &x\ \ge&\ \ \ a\dot- (b\!+\!1)
\end{array}\qquad\quad$$

**Remark** $\ $ With hindsight, one can abstract from the proof a lemma about max, $\ m(x,y)-z\, =\, m(x\!-\!z,y\!-\!z).\,$ Using this shortens the above proof to

$$\begin{align} (a \dot- b) \dot- 1\, &=\,m(m(a\!-\!b,0) -1,\ 0)\\ &=\, m(m(a\!-\!b\!-\!1,-1),0)\\ & =\, m(a\!-\!b\!-\!1,0)\\ &=\,a\dot- (b\!+\!1)\end{align}\qquad\quad $$

Comment: That's excellent. I have a question, though: in the remark, you apply the $m$ function to $m(a-b-1, -1)$. Does that mean that the domain of $m$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ (and not $\mathbb{N}$)?

Comment: Also, in the last step, you're presupposing that, $a-b-1 = a-(b+1)$, right?

Comment: @Nagase Yes.  It was not clear to me precisely what your context was. Are you working in some formal system?

Comment: No, Hodel is not working with an explicit formal system (though the functions are all recursive, and so understood to have domain $\mathbb{N}$. I was a bit confused because Hodel doesn't mention any property of subtraction (as opposed to truncated subtraction) in the book, so I wasn't sure if I could simply assume them for the purposes of the exercise. In any case, I was also curious to see if there was a proof that avoided this assumption (perhaps by working directly with the bounded search operator).

Answer (score 1):

fix $b.$ and consider three cases:
$$(a\dot{-} b) \dot{-} 1 = 
\begin{cases} 0 \dot{-} 1 = 0 & \text{ if } a < b \\
               (a-b)\dot{-}1 = 0  & \text{ if } b < a < b + 1\\
               a-b-1 =a-(b+1) & \text{ if } b + 1 < a \end{cases} $$

therefore $$ (a\dot{-} b) \dot{-} 1 = a\dot{-}(b+1).$$

Comment: As I mentioned in my comments above, I didn't think I was allowed to use that property of "normal" subtraction, at least not without proving it first.

Comment: @Nagase, i didn't know that. i will delete it.

Comment: Well, perhaps I'm the one making things overly complicated. In any case, how would the proof go if we couldn't use that property?

Comment: @Nagase,  only place you use non symbolic math is at $a - b - 1 = a-(b+1)$ in the last case.

Comment: Yes, and how do I prove that $(a-b)-1 = a-(b+1)$?

Comment: @Nagase You prove it using the distributive and commutative laws.  Look at $(a-b)-1-(a-(b+1))$ and show it equals $0$.